# RIO.ByteString.split not working as documented

Tags: haskell, rio

Trying an example from [split docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rio-0.1.18.0/docs/RIO-ByteString.html#v:split):

```
$ stack ghci
...
Prelude> :set -XOverloadedStrings
Prelude> import qualified RIO.ByteString as B
Prelude B> B.split 'a' "aXaXaXa"

<interactive>:3:9: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘GHC.Word.Word8’
                  with actual type ‘Char’
    • In the first argument of ‘B.split’, namely ‘'a'’
      In the expression: B.split 'a' "aXaXaXa"
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = B.split 'a' "aXaXaXa"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is taken from the [`split :: Char -> ByteString -> [ByteString]`  function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#v:split) of the [**`Data.ByteString.Char8`** module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.12.0). This uses the code points 0-255 as `Char` for the corresponding byte.

You can however use the byte value instead. For example `'a'` has as byte value 97, so we can split this with:

```
Prelude> :set -XOverloadedStrings
Prelude> import qualified RIO.ByteString as B
Prelude B> B.split 97 "aXaXaXa"
["","X","X","X",""]
```

Comment: Great, thanks! OK so basically a typo in the docs, right?